# Gigabyte Z590 Motherboard - how to change boot logo?

Tags: bios, motherboard, uefi

I'm struggling to change boot logo for Gigabyte Z590 UD AC motherboard, using @BIOS utility. It successfuly changes the image, but when I reboot, the picture doesn't appear, I can only see black screen with Windows boot animation ring. I tried multiple image resolutions, 800x600, 640x480, nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to prepare background image. It has to be:

```
JPEG, quality: 75, subsampling ON (2x2)
96x96 DPI
Resolution: I tested only original resolution which is 809x116
```